# Typing into a text field then appending it to the text area getting weird output-GUI JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jtextarea

so i'm trying to implement a simple GUI program whereby the user types in the text field then when he presses enter, the text is appended to the text field but i'm getting this kind of output:

[image]

Here's my codes:

TextField.java:

```
package activity1;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class TextField extends JFrame{

private JTextField text;
private JTextArea textArea;

public TextField()
{
    super("Activity 1");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    text = new JTextField(20);
    add(text);

    textArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    add(textArea);

    TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();

    text.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String line = text.getText();
        textArea.append(text + "\n");
        //text.setText("");
    }
}

}
```

And my main TextFieldTEST.java:

```
package activity1;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TextFieldTEST {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TextField myFrame = new TextField();
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setSize(300,200);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the JTextField not its content, and so you're seeing the result of calling `toString()` on this JTextField object. The fix is small and simple:

Change:

```
String line = text.getText();
textArea.append(text + "\n"); // don't use text here
```

to:

```
String line = text.getText();
textArea.append(line + "\n"); // notice the difference? using line here
```

As a side recommendation:

- Put your JTextArea in a JScrollPane and add *that* to the GUI.
- Don't set sizes of your components. Rather `pack()` your GUI and let the layout managers and the components size themselves.
- For instance, I'd use a BorderLayout (which is the default for your JFrame's contentPane), and then add the JTextField BorderLayout.PAGE_START and the JScrollPane that holds the JTextArea BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: @Damini: You're not alone as we've all tripped over these ourselves.

Comment: @Damini: please see additional recommendations.

Comment: Yup pack is a good idea i'll use that instead. And i'll try the JScrollPane. I'm still a beginner in GUI lol.

Comment: I'll surely use your recommendations. Thanks.